# Exception on aws configure in android studio

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

This error I get
     Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/amazonaws/services/cognitosync/AmazonCognitoSync.class

```
THIS IS MY BUILD.GREDLE FILE
//
// Copyright 2016 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates (Amazon). All Rights Reserved.
//
// Code generated by AWS Mobile Hub. Amazon gives unlimited permission to 
// copy, distribute and modify it.
//
// Source code generated from template: aws-my-sample-app-android v0.9
//
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amazon.mysampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.2.18'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/aws-java-sdk-1.10.62.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-java-sdk-1.10.62-sources.jar')

}
```

Comment: What is in your gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below code in the root project folder using terminal

```
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: in which file i have add this

Comment: You have to run in `Terminal`

Comment: can you update the question with the `build.gradle` file

Comment: my email id is devendra.shah.developer@gmail.com please send me your id i mailed you